# I can't display binary content

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple phone book program. I have completed the first function and according to I observe it works without error. However, in second function (which is ""display()"") I can't show to user after I enter person knowledge. I'm working with binary mode. What the problem is in second function I couldn't understand. If you examine and help I'll be satisfied. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>      // "stdlib" library contains of exit() function
#include <malloc.h>     // "malloc" library contains of malloc() function
#include <Windows.h>   // "Windows" library contains of Sleep() function which waits the system as you want
#include <io.h>       // "io" library contains of filelength() function

struct personKnowledge
{
    char name[32];
    char surname[32];
    char number[32];
};

FILE *ptrFILE,*ptrFILE1;
long int recordLength,totalRecordLength,location;
static int counter = 0;
int number,totalRecordNumber;

void newRecord();
void display();
void deletE();
void add();
void update();

int main()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\n\t\t --- Phone Book Program ---");
        printf("\n\n\t\t 1) New record");   // The options are being presented to user
        printf("\n\n\t\t 2) Display person knowledge");
        printf("\n\n\t\t 3) Delete someone");
        printf("\n\n\t\t 5) Update person knowledge");
        printf("\n\n\t\t 6) Exit");
        printf("\n\n\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            newRecord();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            display();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            printf("\nWorking has been completed.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("\nWrong entry! The program has been terminated.\n");
            break;
        }
        }
    } while (choice >= 1 && choice <= 6);
    return 0;
}

void newRecord()
{
    if ((ptrFILE = fopen("Phone Book.dat", "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file couldn't open\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    system("cls");   // Screen is being cleaned
    struct personKnowledge *p;   // p means person
    p = (struct personKnowledge *)malloc(sizeof(struct personKnowledge));   // Memory is being allocated
    fflush(stdin);
    recordLength = sizeof(p);   // size of p
    printf("||  For the %d. person  ||\n", counter+1);
    printf("\n\Express person name: ");   // User is entering the person's knowledge and they are being saved in file
    gets(p->name);
    printf("Express %s's surname: ", p->name);
    gets(p->surname);
    printf("Express %s's number: ", p->name);
    gets(p->number);
    fwrite(&(*p), recordLength, 1, ptrFILE);
    printf("\nPlease wait, information is saving to file..\n");
    Sleep(750);
    printf("*-* Saving operation has been completed succesfully. *-*\n");
    free(p);
    counter++;
    fclose(ptrFILE);
}

void display()
{
    if ((ptrFILE = fopen("Phone Book.dat", "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file couldn't open\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    system("cls");   // Screen is being cleaned
    struct personKnowledge *s;   // s means searching
    s = (struct personKnowledge *)malloc(sizeof(struct personKnowledge));
    fflush(stdin);
    recordLength = sizeof(s);
    totalRecordLength = filelength(fileno(ptrFILE));
    totalRecordNumber = totalRecordLength / recordLength;
    printf("\n\nExpress person record number which you search: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    location = (number - 1)*recordLength;
    fseek(ptrFILE, location, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&(*s), recordLength, 1, ptrFILE);
    printf("\n*-* Person knowledge which you search *-*\n");
    Sleep(750);
    printf("Name: %s\n", s->name);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", s->surname);
    printf("Number: %s\n", s->number);
    free(s);
    fclose(ptrFILE);
}
```

Comment: fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior.

Comment: In first function it helps me to empty buffer. As you say I have deleted from second function ""fflush(stdin)"" but still I can't show knowledge

Comment: `fread(&(*s), recordLength, 1, ptrFILE);` must be `fread(s, recordLength, 1, ptrFILE);`

Comment: Are you trying what you say? :S  When I use second function as you said it shows me again absurd lines so it doesn't work

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as used by `malloc` & friends.

Comment: General remarks: comments like `// p means person ` are useless. Write rather `struct personKnowledge *newperson`, then the comment becomes needless.  `// size of p`  is also totally needless as the code already tells you what is going on.

Comment: @NoWeDoR : BTW `&(*s))` is the same as `s`, so @LPs 's comment is correct, but that's not the problem here (see my answer).

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful

Comment: this line: 'recordLength = sizeof(s);' will return the number of bytes in a pointer (typically 4).  I think the code actually wants the number of malloc'd bytes (96)

Comment: this '&(*s)' becomes 's', and is much clearer.   why have a 'over 10 minutes' pause before displaying the results to the user?   Regarding calls to fread, fseek, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: filelength() is not available on linux/ubuntu. nor is 'io.h'  Suggest using something portable, like 'stat()'

Answer (score 2):

```
recordLength = sizeof(p);
```

is wrong, this is the size of the pointer which is normally 4 on a 32 bit system and 8 on a 64 bit syste.

you need

```
recordLength = sizeof(*p);
```

or

```
sizeof(struct personKnowledge);
```

which gives you the size of the *structure* pointed by `p`.